# WebForms submitting specific form with enter key (not clicking)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, multiple-forms

Say I have one full-page form, but within the form, there are two or more events that need to take place on submission: `Login` & `Register`

Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    EnableViewState="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" 
    Inherits="Site.SiteMasterPage" %>

<!doctype>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <%-- stuff --%>    
</head>
<body>
<form ID="MainForm" action="" runat="server">

    <asp:Login id="LoginControl" runat="server" />    
    <asp:CreateUserWizard id="RegisterControl" runat="server" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If my cursor is focused inside of an `input type="text"` for `asp:Login`, and I hit <kbd>Return</kbd> (with javascript off), the page submits, but I am not logged in.

The same thing happens when I attempt to register (filling out the createUserWizard and hitting the <kbd>Return</kbd> key instead of actually clicking "Register", firing some event)

Is there any non-JavaScript solution for getting the <kbd>Return</kbd> key to submit the proper, currently focused portion of the form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The panel control allows you to define a default button within the scope of it's contents:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="submitButtonA">
 <asp:LinkButton ID="submitButtonA" runat="server" Text="Submit A"/>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="submitButtonB">
 <asp:LinkButton ID="submitButtonB" runat="server" Text="Submit A"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: so this works great an all (thanks!), but it appears to be a solution that only works with JavaScript.. is there any work-around for JavaScript off return key form submission?

Comment: had to do a bit of a hack to get the `asp:createUserWizard` to use the proper DefaultButton if you decide to nest the createUserWizard within an `asp:Panel`. http://www.roastedamoeba.com/blog/archive/2008/06/24/setting-the-default-button-for-a-nested-control

Answer (score 1):

The default button sounds like it might be your friend tonight - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx

Actually it might not be, I haven't ever tried it with no Javascript.

Comment: you can see how to customise the createuserwizard here, http://forums.asp.net/p/1199977/2086200.aspx

Comment: after trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335707/webforms-submitting-specific-form-with-enter-key-not-clicking/6335799#6335799, which is what you've recommended, I've determined that this is a JavaScript-only solution. This is great for the moment, but I would love to find a JS-free solution to this (seemingly fundamental flaw of webforms).

Comment: In serverside OnLoad if Postback etc... you could call the onclick handler for the button? It would have to be the only form on the page to work but it might.